# dataForm jQuery Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

My code does not working correctly, after 3 hours, I don't understand why it isn't working. Can anybody help me out? My goal is to sent over form fields and image to PHP with jQuery. I don't get any respond as XHR. The only thing I see is (Parameters):

```
-----------------------------163541139317822
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="staffnumber"

utyu
-----------------------------163541139317822
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nameperson"

yu
-----------------------------163541139317822
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileupload"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------163541139317822--
```

Error in console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="formadduser" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div id="staffnumber" class="form-group row">
        <label for="staffnumber" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Personeelsnummer</strong> <img src="api/icons/info.svg"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="staffnumber" name="staffnumber" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nameperson" class="form-group row">
        <label for="nameperson" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Naam</strong> <img src="api/icons/info.svg"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="nameperson" name="nameperson" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rowstarttime" class="form-group row">
        <label for="starttime" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Afbeelding</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" id="fileupload" class="custom-file-input" name="fileupload">
            <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="modaladdusersave" class="btn btn-primary mx-sm-3" type="submit">Opslaan</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#formadduser").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);
    alert(formData);
    alert('hoi');
    $.ajax({
        ajax_call: "add_user",
        url: '/api/add.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var data = $.parseJSON( data ); 
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

require_once('../database.php');

if(isset($_GET['ajax_call']) && $_GET['ajax_call'] == 'add_user') {

$staffnumber = $_GET['staffnumber']; // $_GET['staffnumber'];
$nameperson = $_GET['nameperson']; // $_GET['nameperson'];

$file = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];  
$targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['fileupload']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file


// Add record
// $queryNew = 'INSERT INTO Persons (id, name, image) VALUES ("'. $staffnumber .'", "'. $nameperson .'", "test")';
// mysqli_query($conn, $queryNew);

$data = array(
        'staffnumber'   => $staffnumber,
        'nameperson'    => $nameperson,
    );
echo json_encode($data);
exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, u have user type : post in jquery and value get in php using GET method thats why data is not print. print_r($_POST) in php page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `post` method instead of get to get record in php file because you are passing data through jquery is in post method,

```
if(isset($_GET['ajax_call']) && $_GET['ajax_call'] == 'add_user') {
$staffnumber = $_GET['staffnumber']; // $_GET['staffnumber'];
$nameperson = $_GET['nameperson'];
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax_call']) && $_POST['ajax_call'] == 'add_user') {
$staffnumber = $_POST['staffnumber'];
$nameperson = $_POST['nameperson'];
```

And what is `move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)` source path here??,
you have to pass temp file here `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'],$targetPath) ;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rits! I changed this all. But JSON still says: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: do `print_r($data)` before echo `json_encode($data);` so we exactly find the issue.

Comment: Hi Rits, It doesn't show anything. I used the following code to check whats going on, as my json output does not even work: `if(isset($_POST['ajax_call']) && $_POST['ajax_call'] == 'add_user') {
 
 $staffnumber = $_POST['staffnumber']; // $_GET['staffnumber'];
 $nameperson = $_POST['nameperson']; // $_GET['nameperson'];
 
  print_r($data);
  
 $data = array(
   'staffnumber' => $staffnumber,
   'nameperson' => $nameperson,
  );
 echo json_encode($data);

}` Also I noticed, that If I use $_GET, my output JSON works.

Comment: then `echo $staffnumber = $_POST['staffnumber'];` if you getting this then the issue is in php after this,
If not then issue is in your jquery.

Comment: But should I use POST or GET in Jquery and PHP? It does not respond with `echo $staffnumber = $_POST['staffnumber'];` I can give you access via direct link, so you can check browser based, should be possible in a chat.

Comment: use post as you have used post in your jquery

Comment: Perfect. I did that, no solution yet and no error message. Only in console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Comment: what is the output of echo??

Comment: How can I check that output as my jQuery does not output anything?

Comment: hmm is you form data getting any of the data?

Comment: jQuery alerts: [object FormData]

Comment: but the object contains nothing

Comment: first you have to grab all the form data,
check properly in the jquery its getting or not then after go for server side its getting or not. then again the response in jquery,

Comment: pass this to `data` => `data: $("#formadduser").serialize(),` remove form data and check you getting any data in php or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158865/discussion-between-nhatimme-and-rits).

Comment: am sorry brother i have to go now, am leaving office.

Comment: Could you respond later maybe? Cheers!

Comment: Yup tomorrow, as my shift time is over now.

Comment: Can you help me further via the chat?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle the return value of [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

**as a PHP document**

If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

```
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'],$targetPath)

if( $moved ) {
   $data = array(
    'staffnumber'   => $staffnumber,
    'nameperson'    => $nameperson,
);
   echo json_encode($data);        
} else {//something went wrong
   $data = array(
    'error'   => $_FILES["file"]["error"]
    );
   echo json_encode($data);  
}
```

It will give you one of the following error code values 1 to 8:

UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE = Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE = Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL = Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.

UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE = Value: 4; No file was uploaded.

UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR = Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.

UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE = Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.

UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION = Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help.